# How to Highlight Particular Dates in bootstrap full calendar and highlighted dates fetch from database in phpand on click open a table

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

```
 <div data-provide="calendar" id="calendar"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {

        // An array of dates
        var eventDates = {};
        eventDates[ new Date( '2017/04/29' )] = new Date( '2017/04/29' );
        eventDates[ new Date( '2017/05/29' )] = new Date( '2017/05/29' );

        jQuery('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            beforeShowDay: function( date ) {
                var highlight = eventDates[date];
                if( highlight ) {
                     return [true, "event", highlight];
                } else {
                     return [true, '', ''];
                }
             }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: But, events will have start and end date. Right?

Comment: no one specific date

Comment: Just check the answer provided and let me know if any issues occurs.